# how to copy entire linux root filesystem to new hard drive on with ssh and tar

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tar, cat

I need to transfer an entire linux root filesystem off of a failing hard drive onto another computer with an open, available partition. I've pretty sure this involves `tar` and `ssh`, but I can't remember exactly how to do this.

I'm imaging probably using a live cd on the new/target host to run *something* like this:

`ssh user@failingharddrivehost "some tar command | piped into something else"`

Comment: offtopic. not a programming question. but try `ssh user@failingsys "tar cfz - /" > oldsys.tar.gz`

Comment: You want to take care that you do not tar /dev/ (e.g. /dev/random, /dev/sdX, ... ). Ditto /proc/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use rsync. From the new host, you can use

`rsync -avP --numeric-ids --exclude='/dev' --exclude='/proc' --exclude='/sys' root@failedharddrivehost:/ /path/to/destination/`

I wouldn't try involving something like tar because it probably won't work when there are broken files.

Comment: Ended up using rsync, as describe above by etagenklo and @Hennes. Migration went well. Just need to fix grub, but that shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I'd add -AHX as flags to rsync as well in order to preserve acls, xattrs and hardlinks resulting in an even more exact copy of the original fs.

Comment: I'd add -x to ignore items not on the root filesystem, then you can skip the --exclude arguments for various paths.

Comment: rsync -avPAHXx --numeric-ids origin destination/

Answer (score 8):

Why are you combine with directory excluding? Isn't better idea mount the same device into another directory? modern kernels allows this way.
for example, you have mounted

/dev/sda1   as   /
then do:
mkdir /CLEANROOT
mount /dev/sda1 /CLEANROOT

after this you have:
/dev/sda1   as   /
/dev/sda1   as   /CLEANROOT

This is the same filesystem visible with two places, but /CLEANROOT haven't got additive mounts. Then you can tar or rsync /CLEANROOT without any exclusions instead copying / with exclusions.

Of course you must copy another data partitions when you've got some.

Copying partition is first step for server recovery. another is regenerate boot sectors, otherwise system wont boot from copied disk. Usefull is rescue mode when you boot from install/rescue CD or pendrive.

Comment: You can also do it with a bind mount so you don't need to know the device: `mount / /mnt/oldroot -o bind` then confirm you aren't getting the additional mounts: `ls /mnt/oldroot/proc` should be an empty folder.

Answer (score 7):

If both computers are on the same (safe) LAN, I recommend a different approach using `netcat`. This is usually much faster as it doesn't encrypt the data.

```
root@good_host$ cd good_partition; netcat -l -p 1234 | tar xvpmf -
root@bad_host$ tar -cv -f- --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys / | netcat good_host.ip 1234
```

which opens a listening port 1234 on the good machine `netcat -l -p 1234` and pipes the incoming data to `tar` to extract (preserving mtime and permissions). The bad host sends the data to this port, also using `tar` and `netcat`. I included some `--exclude` parameters, as `/proc` and `/sys` are virtual filesystems and hence useless on the new host. (especially the file representing your RAM in (`/proc/kcore`) will add an unnecessary amount of data).

However, you should (also) consider to make a `dd` dump of the failing drive's partitions:

```
user@good_host$ cd good_partition; netcat -l -p 1234 > dump_of_bad_partition_1.dd
root@bad_host$ dd if=/dev/sda1 | netcat good_host.ip 1234
```

where you had to adopt `/dev/sda1` to the right device. Do that with other partitions on the failing drive, too.

With that dump you are sure, that you did not miss any important metadata (like ACLs) which `tar` won't capture.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have physical access to the failing host?

If you do then boot from a live CD. Then use:

- [dump](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dump)  (dump/restores whole filesystems including its permissions).
- [Tar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders) with /dev excluded. You can combine this with outputting to std_out and piping that though netcat
  The exclude syntax is: `tar --exclude='/dev'`.
- or rsync with the same excludes. E.g.
  `rsync -zvr --exclude /dev/ / destination_computer_name_or_ip`
- or [use dd](https://superuser.com/questions/557193/can-i-clone-a-root-file-system-of-a-running-server-via-ssh) like this:

  `nc -l 4242 | gunzip | cat > my_full_disk_backup_of_PC_named_foo`

  `dd if=/dev/sda of=- bs=1M | gzip | nc -p 4242 name_of_the_destination`

If you can not boot from a live CD then some most of the above solutions will stay the same, but:

1. Some files may be in use/locked.
2. Make sure to exclude not just /dev/ but also /proc/.
   E.g. `tar --exclude='/dev' --exclude='/proc'`

Comment: Yes I have physical (and root) access to both hosts. Going to try with rsync. the netcat crashed for the failing box for unknown reasons. the target filesystem doesn't want to be mounted. it fails with: 
`#mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/fedora`

`mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'`

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a description of how to copy files using `tar` and `ssh`.](https://serverfault.com/questions/39027/easiest-way-for-fast-transfer-of-files-between-linux-servers/39111#39111) Basically, you would run one of the following, depending on whether you want to copy local -> remote or remote -> local:

```
tar cf - files... | ssh remotehost -c 'cd /destination && tar xvf -'

ssh remotehost -c 'cd /destination && tar cf - files' | tar xvf -
```

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using rsync

the follwoing command assumes 2 things:

1. you are on the system with failing hard drive
2. new partition has a minimal linux installation with ssh enabled.

`rsync / new_partition:/wherever/you/want/`

Note: the trailing / is important, otherwise your files will end up in one directory level above

Comment: The OP probably want to use the `-a` parameter (and perhaps the `-A`), as it preserves times, ownership, symlinks (and perhaps ACLs) etc. and the `-e ssh` parameter, as the data should be transferred to another computer. So `rsync -aAv -e ssh root@failingharddrivehost:/ /good_computer/newpartition_mountpoint`

Answer (score 0):

### Clone a live root file system using tar

Let's say you want to clone a live Ubuntu root file system to an unused
partition `/dev/sdc5` on the same disk.  `/dev/sdc5` size must be no less than the
data occupied by the root partioned being cloned. Let's assume that an EFI
partition is `/dev/sdc1`.

- Format the destination partition and use a label to identify it

```
mkfs.ext4 -L Ubuntu-sdc5 -J size=128 /dev/sdc5

mkdir /tmp/{dstRoot,srcRoot}
mount /dev/sdc5 /tmp/dstRoot # destination root
mount --bind / /tmp/srcRoot # source root
```

- Clone the current root to `/dev/sdc5` mounted partition

```
tar -C /tmp/srcRoot -cf - . | tar -C /tmp/dstRoot -xf -
```

- Edit `/tmp/dstRoot/etc/fstab` to reflect the new label assigned to `/dev/sdc5`:

```
LABEL=Ubuntu-sdc5 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

- Mount EFI VFAT parition

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /tmp/dstRoot/boot/efi
```

- Clone the current Ubuntu EFI folder

```
mkdir /tmp/dstRoot/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu2
rsync -av /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/ /tmp/dstRoot/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu2/
```

- Edit `/tmp/dstRoot/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu2/grub.cfg` to reflect the new label
  `Ubuntu-sdc5` and partition `gpt5`

```
search.fs_label Ubuntu-sdc5 root hd2,gpt5
```

- Mount the necessary folders for `grub-mkconfig`

```
for i in dev dev/pts proc sys run; do mount -B /$i /tmp/dstRoot/$i; done
```

- Reconfigure grub on the cloned root file system

```
chroot /tmp/dstRoot
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
exit # exit chroot

for i in run sys proc dev/pts dev; do umount /tmp/dstRoot/$i; done
umount /tmp/dstRoot/boot/efi
umount /tmp/dstRoot
umount /tmp/srcRoot
rmdir /tmp/{dstRoot,srcRoot}
```

- Reboot into the EFI setup menu and add a new boot entry to boot options

```
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

NOTE: The EFI boot software should automatically detect a new boot entry, but
if it doesn't, boot to the original root and try to add it manually:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdc -p 1 -L "Ubuntu2" -l "\EFI\ubuntu2\shimx64.efi"
```

- Reboot again into the EFI setup menu and add a new boot entry to boot options